# Action Cable Detect Multiple Connections/Tabs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I am using Action Cable and was wondering how you would detect if you have multiple tabs or connections for the same user open and delete them if necessary. I am having a download task execute multiple times and I only want it to execute once.

```
    class ListsChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
      def subscribed
        stream_from "channel"
      end
    # # TODO code to detect multiple streams and delete them if tabs.

      # def unsubscribed
      # end


    end
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Note:** this is probably not the exact answer you're looking for, but it might inspire you or others for a different solution.

I got to this question having a similar issue, but then about showing the same notifications on multiple tabs.

For me the solution is actually build into the the [Notifications API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API/Using_the_Notifications_API#Dealing_with_repeated_notifications), by using a `tag`, it would only show the notification once on multiple tabs:

```
let notification = new Notification('Hey!', {
    body : 'So nice to hear from you',
    tag : 'greeting-notify',
    icon : 'https://example.org/my_funny_icon.png'
});
```

Maybe for you the solution could be to use this API to push your download link to:

```
Notification.requestPermission().then(function (result) {})

import consumer from "./consumer"

consumer.subscriptions.create("ReportNotificationChannel", {
    connected() {},

    disconnected() {},

    received(data) {
        if (Notification.permission === 'granted') {
            let title = `Your file is ready!`
            let options = { body: 'Click here to start downloading.', tag: data['filename']} // Assuming filename is something unique
            let notification = new Notification(title, options)
            notification.onclick = function(event){
                window.location.href = `/downloads/${data['filename']}`
            }
        }
    }
});
```